# How does the writing of the Vue sub component JSX get the passing $attrs?

Tags: vue.js, jsx

Now the situation is like this.

My sub component is written in JSX, the parent component passes information into props, the sub components are not collected by `this.$attrs`, but how do I write it into JSX now?

If it is written like this, it doesn't work, I've tried several ways.:
[image: If it is written like this, it doesn't work, I've tried several ways.]

This is my father's component；
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZryiS.png)

Comment: Could you please provide the whole listening of the component?

Comment: I provide my father component

Answer (score 0):

I found a new way to solve this problem.